# Is it possible to have a double select with ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to obtain a select with two choices like this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [teamtreehouse.com](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/date.png))</sub>

I'm using Ionic 1 and angular.

Comment: please explain in brief

Comment: It's a select in iOs (in this case) with which you can choose a value and the decimal value: somitheing like this: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/date.png

Comment: in that case you can have two selects and getting a single value with them is the logic behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes but then it looks not so nice, if I have two different selects

Comment: If you want like that, you must generate options dynamically with single select